# Attemoting to get browsersync to work from Gulp

Tags: gulp

Have been unable to get Browsersync working in Gulp.
I have installed the standard JointsWP build (this is a wordpress/foundation mash up), but the following gulpfile doesn't kick off browsersync at all.

I am using MAMP and the site works fine.

Tried a few things but limited gulpfile knowledge.
thanks in advance.

```
// Grab our gulp packages
var gulp  = require('gulp'),
gutil = require('gulp-util'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'),
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
stylish = require('jshint-stylish'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
concat = require('gulp-concat'),
rename = require('gulp-rename'),
plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
bower = require('gulp-bower'),
babel = require('gulp-babel'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Compile Sass, Autoprefix and minify
gulp.task('styles', function() {
return gulp.src('./assets/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(plumber(function(error) {
        gutil.log(gutil.colors.red(error.message));
        this.emit('end');
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // Start Sourcemaps
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
        cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css/'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // Creates sourcemaps for minified 
styles
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css/'))
});

// JSHint, concat, and minify JavaScript
gulp.task('site-js', function() {
return gulp.src([   

       // Grab your custom scripts
      './assets/js/scripts/*.js'

])
.pipe(plumber())
.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
.pipe(jshint())
.pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
.pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/js'))
.pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // Creates sourcemap for minified JS
.pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/js'))
});    

// JSHint, concat, and minify Foundation JavaScript
gulp.task('foundation-js', function() {
return gulp.src([   

      // Foundation core - needed if you want to use any of the 
components below
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.*.js',

      // Pick the components you need in your project
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.abide.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.accordion.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.accordionMenu.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.drilldown.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.dropdown.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.dropdownMenu.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.equalizer.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.interchange.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.magellan.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.offcanvas.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.orbit.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.responsiveMenu.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.responsiveToggle.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.reveal.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.slider.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.sticky.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.tabs.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.toggler.js',
      './vendor/foundation-sites/js/foundation.tooltip.js',
])
.pipe(babel({
    presets: ['es2015'],
    compact: true
}))
.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
.pipe(concat('foundation.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/js'))
.pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // Creates sourcemap for minified 
Foundation JS
.pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/js'))
}); 

// Update Foundation with Bower and save to /vendor
gulp.task('bower', function() {
return bower({ cmd: 'update'})
.pipe(gulp.dest('vendor/'))
});  

// Browser-Sync watch files and inject changes
gulp.task('browsersync', function() {
// Watch files
var files = [
    './assets/css/*.css', 
    './assets/js/*.js',
    '**/*.php',
    'assets/images/**/*.{png,jpg,gif,svg,webp}',
];

browserSync.init(files, {
    // Replace with URL of your local site
    proxy: "s18.dev",
});

gulp.watch('./assets/scss/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
gulp.watch('./assets/js/scripts/*.js', ['site-js']).on('change',  
browserSync.reload);

});

// Watch files for changes (without Browser-Sync)
gulp.task('watch', function() {

  // Watch .scss files
  gulp.watch('./assets/scss/**/*.scss', ['styles']);

  // Watch site-js files
  gulp.watch('./assets/js/scripts/*.js', ['site-js']);

  // Watch foundation-js files
  gulp.watch('./vendor/foundation-sites/js/*.js', ['foundation-js']);

}); 

// Run styles, site-js and foundation-js
gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.start('styles', 'site-js', 'foundation-js');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It was in fact my lack of gulp knowledge....

On closer inspection of the gulpfile, there were 2 functions - one with BS and one without...

I was running 'gulp watch' with no joy, whereas simply running 'gulp browsersync' did the trick.

bonza.